# Building RSS Vacancy Feed

Tags: rss, feed, xml-namespaces

I've built an RSS feed for a client to share their vacancies. However, they've now decided they want to add a couple of extra fields (Salary and Location) and I'm having some trouble working out how to do it and get a valid RSS feed.

I can't believe I'm the first person to want to add a salary and location to a vacancy feed, but I'm struggling to find a namespace that will let me do this!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered such extension.

I recommend creating it yourself and document it (this is important so other people can find and benefit from your extension)

1. Put location and salary in the description so that generalized RSS reader can at least display it.
2. Handle salary and location in your vacancy extension so specialized RSS reader that consume it.

Creating your own namespace is a valid way to extend RSS 2.0. This is a good source on how to do it http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-wxxm36/